# Mystery device sdg is logging errors. How do I find out what this is?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian

I have an interesting problem on my home file/media server that I can't track down(debian 8.11).  I am constantly seeing the following message in dmesg for the last few days:

```
Buffer I/O error on device sdg, logical block 5
```

Sometime I'll get a bit more in the logs

```
[331645.357795] Buffer I/O error on device sdg, logical block 7
[331826.255867] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdg] Command timed out
[331826.255875] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdg]  
[331826.255879] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[331826.255883] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdg]  
[331826.255886] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[331826.255892] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdg]  
[331826.255896] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming 
ready
[331826.255899] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdg] CDB: 
[331826.255902] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[331826.255915] end_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 0
[331826.257606] Buffer I/O error on device sdg, logical block 0
[331833.213945] sd 14:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[331833.215687] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdg] Command timed out
[331833.215692] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdg]  
[331833.215695] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[331833.215699] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdg]  
[331833.215701] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[331833.215717] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdg]  
[331833.215731] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming 
ready
[331833.215735] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdg] CDB: 
[331833.215737] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 07 00
```

The problem is, I can't find a figure out what device sdg is?!?!

I am assuming it's block device of some sort, however there are only 6 physical drives in my server(sda, sdb, sdc, sdd, sde, sdf)

- sda = OS installation drive. Physical disk.
- sdb & sdc - MDADM RAID 0 as /dev/md1. Physical disks.
- sdd & sde - MDADM RAID 0 as /dev/md0. Physical disks.
- sdf - External USB drive used for nightly backups.

I've tried running `fdisk -l /dev/sdg` and the command just hangs.

`ls -all /dev/disk/by-id/ | grep sdg` returns 0 results.

I plugged in a USB thumb drive and it mounted as /dev/sdh, so it skipped /dev/sdg for some reason.

`smartctl -a /dev/sdg` returns the following:

```
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-4-amd64] (local 
build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, 
www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error device will be ready soon

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or 
more '-T permissive' options.
```

`cat /proc/diskstats` returns:

```
   8      96 sdg 596 867 1458 163968604 0 0 0 0 1 68509944 164194776
```

There is nothing in /etc/fstab referencing /dev/sdg.

Other than running samba/ssh for sharing files on my home network, the only other application installed is Plex media server, however I wouldn't think any of those applications would be creating block devices on my system.

It's a bit of a relief to know that it's not any of my disks holding my data that are throwing errors, but now the question is how do I figure out what sdg is and why is it throwing these errors?

Any ideas on how I track this sdg drive down?

Comment: There's only 6 physical drives in your computer, and they're all accounted for with sda-sdf... is there another wire connected to some other device? Or some USB? Unplugging USB devices and watching logs & for /dev/sdg to disappear... Or searching earlier logs for when sdg arrived

Comment: Just double checked, only 2 usb cables plugged into it.  1 goes to the external USB drive(sdf), and the other is the keyboard.  I've had that old keyboard for at least a decade too, so I doubt it's anything wonky with that.

Comment: So you unplugged everything USB and sdg was still there? Your other comment mentions a 4GB usb drive, and sdg is 4GB... what happens when you unplug it? I don't usually like to recommend a reboot, but in case sdg is some type of broken orphan...

Answer (score 1):

In theory `lsblk -O /dev/sdg` should tell you a lot. There are two problems though:

1. Faulty device may report little anyway.
2. Usually the output of `lsblk -O` is cryptic because long lines get wrapped in the terminal, the entire output becomes unreadable. To overcome this:

   - use a pager with handy horizontal scrolling, e.g.:

     ```
     lsblk -O /dev/sdg | less -S -# 8
     ```
   - or redirect to a file (`lsblk -O /dev/sdg >/tmp/lsblk_sdg`) and examine the file in any editor that can show non-wrapped lines and scrolls properly;
   - or view few columns at a time, like `lsblk -o VENDOR,MODEL,SERIAL` (run `lsblk --help` to know all available columns).

Alternatively `cd` to `/sys/class/block/sdg/device` and see what you can find (e.g. `cat model`). Again, if the device is faulty, you may not be able to retrieve much information.

Additionally find entries in `dmesg` (or in logs) from when the device was first discovered after reboot. They may or may not tell you something.

Comment: This is interesting.  lsblk returned the following line "sdg                             8:96   0   3.9G  0 disk "

Comment: so it's a 3.9 gig disk.  I just went through every usb port and am not seeing anything plugged in that shouldn't be there.  the 2 data partitions are encrypted(LUKS) and I use luks passdev script to unlock them on boot using a key stored on a USB thumb drive, which coincidentally happens to be 4GB.  I've been running this setup for years, is it possible the USB thumb drive didn't properly unmount after decrypting the drives and is now hanging out as a broken /dev/sdg block device?